# Force Sensitive Resistor SPICE Simulation does not show voltage change

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, schematics, fsr

I have done a SPICE simulation on LTSpice to double check before I order my custom PCB. I want to graph the voltage change after the op-amp to see how it is affected once I press on the force sensitive resistor.

In my head the voltage should go from 4V to 0V depending on how hard I press on the FSR, but in the simulation I get a constant 2.6V with no change... Am I doing something wrong in the simulation, or is there a logical flaw in my schematic?

In my simulation I have the resistor "FSR" go from 1 Ohm to 100k Ohm to simulate someone pressing the FSR.

The op-amp is LM358, which was advised by the FSR Datasheet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The op-amp is LM358*

An LM358 with a supply of 4 volts will not work with inputs greater than about 2 volts: -

[image]

You are trying to put 4 volts into the chip.

The LM358 output is maxed-out at around 1.5 volts lower than the supply voltage. That's 2.5 volts.

> *In my head the voltage should go from 4V to 0V depending on how hard I
> press on the FSR, but in the simulation I get a constant 2.6V with no
> change... Am I doing something wrong in the simulation, or is there a
> logical flaw in my schematic?*

Ignoring the limitations of the op-amp, you circuit does not form a potential divider hence, it will not produce a variable voltage with the parameter step regime you are using. You need to use the FSR in some kind of potential divider arrangement. Currently, the voltage at the op-amp input will be always 4 volts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help. I am slightly confused, as in the datasheet, it says that the LM358 can have a supply voltage Vs of 3-30V. Why would it not work with inputs greater than 2V? Is this something I can find in the datasheet, or is this common electrical engineering knowledge that I do not have yet? Maybe a stupid question, but it is not only in the sim that I need a potential divider, correct? It would be needed in the physical PCB as well.

Comment: The data sheet tells you that the maximum operational working input voltage is around 2 volts lower than the power rail. You have a 4 volt power rail. As a rule of thumb you can never hope to exceed the supply rails with inputs or outputs and, generally, it's a volt or so inside the rails on average @Prolik_ the potential divider is needed to make it work so, it's needed for real hardware too.

Comment: Ah, I see. So then if I supply my FSRs with +4V, does that mean that I should have a 6V power rail minimum to be able to read 0-4V after the op-amp?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good start @Prolik_

Comment: I have one last question that I am slightly confused about. Why is that in the datasheet there is a (V+)-1.5 and a (V+)-2? I assume this is where your "The LM358 output is maxed-out at around 1.5 volts lower than the supply voltage" comes from, correct?

Comment: @Prolik_ the 1.5 volts reduction is at ambient temperature. The 2 volt reduction is across the full range of temperature. It's right there in the image in my answer. But, of course, I'm well-versed in looking at these things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, everything makes so much more sense to me :) Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 2):

You should read about the behaviour and shortcomings of the LM358 in [its datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf). All op-amps have certain constraints and quirks that must be considered in designs that use them, all detailed in their datasheets. In that document you will be able to find out that:

1. You have a 4V positive supply. This limits the LM358 output to about 3V maximum.
2. That same 4V supply limits the acceptable input range to well below 3V.

You are connecting the FSR between a 4V source and the op-amp input. This applies a permanent 4V to the op-amp input, regardless of FSR resistance, violating (2). Even if that were OK, the op-amp still can't get its output up to 4V.

You need to use the FSR as a member of a resistor potential divider. Here's a circuit that will do better:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX78xy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will produce a potential at X between +0.36V to +3.3V as the FSR resistance goes from 100kΩ to 1Ω.

You can [learn about potential dividers here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/voltage-divider-calculator/). Changing R1 and R2 will alter the minimum and maximum potentials obtainable at X. You can even swap and change the positions of those three resistances, to obtain different behaviour and ranges.

Whether you need an op-amp at all depends entirely on what you intend to connect to X.

Comment: I want to connect X to the ADC of my microcontroller(STM32F446RET6). I saw this written in the datasheet: "Suggested opamps for single sided supply designs are LM358 and LM324.  The low bias currents of these op-amps reduce the error due to the source impedance of the voltage divider. " and assumed that I should add the op-amp too.

Comment: @Prolik_ Maybe you should, then. Still, you'll need to consider the range of input and output voltages that the op-amp can deal with when its positive and negative supplies are 4V and 0V.